# How to concatenate strings fields for same ID when UNION in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, union, concatenation

I have the following SELECT:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
   V1.FORPDM_ID AS HVID,
   1 AS IMPORT_STATUS,
   V1.CREATEDAT AS IMPORT_DATE,
   'ok' AS IMPORT_MESSAGE,
   V1.ID AS AT_ID,
   V1.FORPDM_TRANSACTION_ID AS TRANSACTION_ID
 FROM V_VALIDATIONCARRIER V1, V_FORPDM_DAVE_HWDEMAND V2
 WHERE
   V1.FORPDM_ID = V2.HVID AND -- JOIN CONDITION
   ...other conditions...
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT DISTINCT
   V1.FORPDM_ID AS HVID,
   0 AS IMPORT_STATUS,
   V1.CREATEDAT AS IMPORT_DATE,
   'PC_ID is null or not in V_PLANNINGCATEGORY' AS IMPORT_MESSAGE,
   V1.ID AS AT_ID,
   V1.FORPDM_TRANSACTION_ID AS TRANSACTION_ID
 FROM V_VALIDATIONCARRIER V1, V_FORPDM_DAVE_HWDEMAND V2
 WHERE (V1.FORPDM_ID = V2.HVID) AND -- JOIN CONDITION
     ...some error conditions...
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT DISTINCT
   V1.FORPDM_ID AS HVID,
   0 AS IMPORT_STATUS,
   V1.CREATEDAT AS IMPORT_DATE,
   'BAUPHASE is null or not in V_SPEEDSPECIFICMASTERDATA' AS IMPORT_MESSAGE,
   V1.ID AS AT_ID,
   V1.FORPDM_TRANSACTION_ID AS TRANSACTION_ID
 FROM V_VALIDATIONCARRIER V1, V_FORPDM_DAVE_HWDEMAND V2
 WHERE (V1.FORPDM_ID = V2.HVID) AND -- JOIN CONDITION
       ...some other error conditions...
)
```

In my database there are rows that can match both the error conditions and I would like to concatenate the two `IMPORT_MESSAGE` when this happens, so that I don't get two rows with the same `HVID` and two different `IMPORT_MESSAGE`.
Is there a way to achieve that in Oracle when I am using also the `UNION` as in my query?

**EDIT**
After some tests, it worked. Just one clarification: to have all my data *and* the message I should select like in the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT HVID, IMPORT_STATUS, IMPORT_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, AT_ID, LISTAGG(IMPORT_MESSAGE, ',') 
   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IMPORT_MESSAGE) AS 
      IMPORT_MESSAGE FROM ( ...my union all select... ) MYUNION 
   GROUP BY HVID, IMPORT_STATUS, IMPORT_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID, AT_ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to use `LISTAGG` function in Oracle environment.

For example (see at: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/group_concat):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(IMPORT_MESSAGE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)
FROM (
    .... your union all select
     ) as YOURUNION
GROUP BY YOURUNION.IMPORT_MESSAGE;
```

I have no Oracle Database, so you have to try.